# Launch Setting activity then create a dialogue

Tags: android

In my app I'd like to send the user to the device setting then create a dialogue asking him to enable something. the problem is the dialogue is always created in my app not the setting activity. [I'm trying to make it look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gure0.png)

launch setting activity:

```
Intent overLay = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(overLay);
```

and creating a dialogue:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

dialog.dismiss();
}
});
alertDialog.show();
```

I've already tried using a new thread but it didn't work. the only thing that kind of works is a toast but not a dialogue.